# Peoplesoft Integration Broker REST services POST - how to set up in Peoplesoft

Tags: rest, post, integration, peoplesoft

This is the first time that I am setting a POST up in Peoplesoft, so need some input. The Service Operation needs to be set up with the parameters in the BODY, as I understand. I was fine with setting up GET, since all the parameters come in via the URL/URI.
How do I configure the Service Operation for the POST? I have set up the document and the message already.
We receive in json-format.

Comment: I haven't done it enough to answer, but I have turn to Chris Malek's Cedar Hills Group resources when it comes to this sort of thing. Here are two POST examples from his site: [asynchornous](https://ib.books.cedarhillsgroup.com/examples/async-example1/) and [synchronous](https://ib.books.cedarhillsgroup.com/examples/sync-example1/).

Answer (score 0):

Since it a very high leve question, I'm gonna refer you to peoplebooks. Refer to page.219 in the below peoplebook. You can also find a lot of blog posts on the same topic.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F52214_01/psft/pdf/pt859tibr-b032022.pdf

On high level, to give you a head start,

1. create document definition
2. attach it to message definition
3. create service operation definition and use this message definition for request
4. create a message definition for response based on the expected structure
5. populate the document body and invoke the service operation from peoplecode.(refer attached peoplebook for code reference)

Please post a question with specifics if you get stuck somewhere.